# Can't stop actionBar home icon from acting as a button

Tags: android

I need to stop the app icon in the upper left corner on the actionBar from acting as a button. I tried using actionBar.setHomeEnabled(false), but it isn't working and i'm not sure why. Any help is really appreciated. This is my onCreate method:

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sound_board);

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);

    if(fragment == null){
        fragment = new SoundBoardFragment();
        fm.beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment)
            .commit();
    }

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will also need to call `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false)`

Comment: You can improve your answer by providing some context. Where should OP include setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false) and more importantly, why?

Comment: @MarsAtomic I could update the answer if I hear back from okkhoury, but they don't seem to provide feedback as to whether or not something else was the issue and this was irrelevant.  I don't spend long periods of time on answers if the thread's creator has no interest on spending time on it either.

Comment: Fair enough Jay. Please bear in mind that the OP isn't the only one who is going to see your answer. Other SO users can benefit from your knowledge if you flesh out the answer a bit more with the reasons behind why you suspect that your answer was correct.